# Is there a way that run different jmx scripts distributively on different machines?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed

I have 5 different jmeter scripts. And these 5 different jmeter scripts were prepared in 5 different jmx files.

1. Test1.jmx
2. Test2.jmx
3. Test3.jmx
4. Test4.jmx
5. Test5.jmx

I want to run these 5 jmx files distributively on different machines. In my architecture, I want to have one master and 5 slaves. This master will control 5 slaves.

For instance:

Test1.jmx file run on -> Machine 1 (10.0.0.1)

Test2.jmx file run on -> Machine 2 (10.0.0.2)

Test3.jmx file run on -> Machine 3 (10.0.0.3)

Test4.jmx file run on -> Machine 4 (10.0.0.4)

Test5.jmx file run on -> Machine 5 (10.0.0.5)

These jmx files will be run concurently and will be controlled by one master.

As I know that Jmeter has remote(distrubted) testing feature. But it supports that only one jmeter script (jmx file) run on different machines. However, it is not what I expect from jmeter.

Is there a solution for my case in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool to run multiple JMX files in parallel.

For more information [Taurus - Working with multiple jmx](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests).